# Powershell - Access global synchronized hash table from custom event handler

Tags: multithreading, powershell, event-handling

I'm trying to access `$syncHash` inside the event handler scriptblock, but seems nothing happened. Is there a way to to it?

```
$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$syncHash.PostPocess = {
    [string]$path = $event.messagedata
    ...
    # trying to access $syncHash here, but failed
    ...
}

Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier Process_Result -Action $syncHash.PostPocess
New-Event -SourceIdentifier Process_Result -MessageData $path
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event script block has no access to the initial PowerShell environment from which you have registered the event.

One solution can be to pass the synchronized hash through the MessageData handler of the event, here is your revised code for that :

```
$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})

$syncHash.PostPocess = {

    # Your $path variable is now in the first cell of the array $event.messagedata
    [string]$path = $event.messagedata[0]

    ...

    # Should display 'True', as $event.MessageData[1] is now your initial $syncHash
    echo $event.MessageData[1].IsSynchronized

    ...

}

Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier Process_Result -Action $syncHash.PostPocess

New-Event -SourceIdentifier Process_Result -MessageData @($path, $syncHash)
```

With an array, you can use the `MessageData` member of the `$event` as an arguments line.

Comment: Thanks, Zilog80:-) I didn’t realize I can pass an array. Will try it today. Seems we are in the same age as I used to play with Z80 asm more than 30 years ago.